# External Keyboard key remapping

Tags: macos, keyboard, bootcamp, pc

I recently bought a CM Storm QuickFire keyboard. This keyboard is made for Windows. It works perfectly on Bootcamp, but when I use it on the OS X side, the keys are completely remapped.

the <kbd>F</kbd> key acts like <kbd>F</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd>
etc.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or how to completely remap a keyboard?

Extra info:
I used an identical keyboard on a work computer (Mac) and it worked well. Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (previously KeyRemap4MacBook)

This app can remap every key on your keyboard.

Comment: There are versions of this app from 10.5 to 10.11; highly recommended.